# How to pass Different object variables which is getters in the below code for loop?

Tags: java, oop

How to pass Different variables which is getters in the below codes for loop???

```
public class HtmlTags extends Employee {
public HtmlTags() {
}

static HtmlTags htags;
static String[][] tags = { { "<tr>", "</tr>" }, { "<th>", "</th>" },
        { "<td>", "</td>" }, { "<>", "</>" } };
String tag;

public HtmlTags(int sno, String empName, int days, String tag) {
    super(sno, empName, days);
    this.tag = tag;
}

public static String htmlAppend(String tag) {
    Employee emp = new Employee(1, "balaji", 10);
    String result = "";
    int row = tags.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (tag.equals(tags[i][j])) {
                row = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (row == HtmlTags.tags.length) {
        result += "search failed to return any results";
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                result += HtmlTags.tags[row][j] + emp.getEmployeeName()
                        + HtmlTags.tags[row][j + 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return result;

}

}
```

output is: 
`tr balaji /tr tr balaji /tr tr balaji /tr`

expected output: 
`tr balaji /tr tr 1 /tr tr 10 /tr`

i need to pass employee  variables(getters ) one by one. Any help experts?

Comment: Can you add what is the output that you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this in the else block

```
if (row == HtmlTags.tags.length) {
    result += "search failed to return any results";
} else {
   result = HtmlTags.tags[row][0] + emp.getEmployeeName()
                    + HtmlTags.tags[row][1];
   result += HtmlTags.tags[row][0] + emp.getEmployeeSNo()
                    + HtmlTags.tags[row][1];
   result += HtmlTags.tags[row][0] + emp.getEmployeeDays()
                    + HtmlTags.tags[row][1];       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note: you code is **awfully** "low-level". This means that you are using many concepts that, yes work; but that require a lot of small details to work.

For example: don't use a two dimensional array. Instead, you could create a **real** class for HtmlTags; something that works like:

```
class HtmlTag {
   private final String tagName;
   HtmlTag(String tagName) { this.tagName; }

   String embedInTag(String message) {
     return "<" + tagName + "> " + message + "</" + tagName +">";
   }
```

Meaning: good programming is all about creating **useful abstractions**. Your code doesn't abstract anything; and I am tempted to say: therefore your code itself is really rally abstract, complex, hard to read, and will be **hard** to maintain over time.

Finally: you made HtmlTag a **child class** of Employee. From an OO perspective, that is absolutely **horrible**. You see, good OO design is **much** more than just putting *extends* here or the because it seems convenient! Instead inheritance is about "child **is a** parent". And, no, a HtmlTag is **never** an Employee!

There are a lot of important concepts to know and understand, and if you miss those, the code that you create .. well, looks like the mess you are showing here. This is not meant to be rude, just a hint that you seriously should look into such topics! One starting point: [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design principles.